# how to prevent duplicate records in database

Tags: primary-key, duplicate-data

**Question:**

How do I prevent two different admin users of a website from creating a customer record with the same customer id.

Background information:

The website I'm working with autogenerates a number called "customer number" based on a routine/method that does the following:

1. checks the allowable range of numbers by using the cust_number_range table.
2. figures out the highest number in use from the customer table.
3. displays the next available number on the "create new customer" form.
4. when the submit button is clicked, before attempting to save the record, i double check the customer table again to make sure the number i have calculated as the next available one is not in use.  if it's still ok, then i save to the database.

Here's what the database looks like:

```
customer table
=====================
id           integer - primary key
custnumber   integer
fname        varchar(255)
lname        varchar(255)

cust_number_range
====================
lower_range integer
upper_range integer
id  integer - primary key
```

The problem I've run into is if two admins click on the "submit" new cust record at the exact same time, the system will create two records with the same custnumber.
Here are some questions that I have:

1. Is making the custnumber field a part of the pk optional?  meaning, is that really the "proper" solution?
2. what other ways do i have to solve the problem?

thanks.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using, it makes a difference on how you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use unique columns for that. But I would also check from code, before adding user to the database, check if user does not exists, and if not, only then add.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the numbers to be in sequence?
You can create an "index" table.

```
index_table
====================
index_type integer (possible values - 1 for customers, 2 for orders, etc.)
last_index integer
```

Every time you create a new customer create an index for the user from the index table by advancing the last_index id field.
If the user does not save the record, you just skip an id.

Most databases though have a record_id which has a similar mechanism, so I would recommend using that.